# ASP Image, set ImageUrl to client path

Tags: asp.net

Really, I want to set the ImageUrl path to a client path, not server.
In my app, the user browses to a local image file and I display it in a thumbnail using javascript. If the user navigates away from the image, I cache the url path in a Session variable. When the user navigates back to the image I need to display the image using the cached path (which is a client local path).

image.ImageUrl = something does not work if the cached url contains white space. I've tried quotes, encoding methods, regex.replace etc w/no luck.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.
Peter

This works: use an html img (with runat=server) instead of an asp:Image

Comment: by you mentioning 'runat=server' it seems to me you're using asp.net, not asp-classic (if so, retag so you get better results)